# Method returns a value which is not in the table

Tags: c#, methods, return-value

This method takes an input parameter (email address). If it exists in the table then it returns the value (email), if it doesn't then it shouldn't be returning any value but this method keeps on returning the same value (parameter) all the time.

Am I missing something?

```
private static string findEmailSubscription(string emailAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            //Fetch email Address
            using (DataAccess data = new DataAccess("Email"))
            {
                DynamicEntity[] emails = data.Adapter.Execute(
                    "SELECT EmailAddress FROM table " +
                    "WHERE EmailAddress=@EmailAddress; ",
                    ExecuteCommandType.Text,
                    new Object[,] {
                    {"EmailAddress", emailAddress ?? (object)DBNull.Value}
                });
            }

            return emailAddress;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
return emailAddress;
```

That's unconditional. You're not *using* your `emails` variable at all. How did you expect this to work? (Not that this can be your complete code anyway, given that you have a `try` block with no `catch` or `finally`...)

Note that a method with a return type can't "return no value". It could never return (not good), throw an exception, or return a value. That's all it can do. It could return a null reference... is that what you want it to do?

Comment: applogise, missed to print the catch statement, I've been calling this method into other methods, e.g. var value = findEmailSubscription(Model.email) but when I try to use condition such as If (!string.IsemptyOrNull(value)), it returns the same input parameter which is not in the table.

Comment: @xxxpurt: Well as I said, you're returning `emailAddress` whatever happens, so how would you expect that to change?

Comment: if (emails.Length > 0)
                    {
                        emailAddress = emails[0]["EmailAddress"].ToString();
                    }

Comment: if I add above statements, would it be feasible?

Comment: @xxxpurt: Well that's still going to return the original value if `emails.Length` is 0, isn't it?

Comment: DynamicEntity[] emails = data.Adapter.Execute(
                        "SELECT EmailAddress FROM table " +
                        "WHERE EmailAddress=@EmailAddress; ",
                        ExecuteCommandType.Text,
                        new Object[,] {
                        {"EmailAddress", emailAddress ?? (object)DBNull.Value}
                    });

Comment: to avoid null or 0, I've used the condition at the end of the execute procedure

Comment: @xxxpurt: Well you still haven't said what you *want* the return value to be if the original value isn't valid. I think you need to rethink the whole method from scratch instead of just trying things almost at random and hoping they'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the same value that you passed as parameter .

```
findEmailSubscription(string emailAddress)
(..)
return emailAddress;
```

you should do

```
return emails ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You always return emailAddress. The stuff you do in the method body does not alter the retun value in any way. If you want to return something based on what the query returns you need to check the results of your query and construct a return value from there (i.e. return email address if found and null if not).

If you want the raw resultset you can always just return `emails`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jon who gave me superb hints. I have re-written the method which works fine:

```
public string previousEmail   //Global variable - gets value from other source

public string FindEmailSubscription()
{
   try
   {
      string email = null;

      using (DataAccess data = new DataAccess())
      {            
          data.Execute(
               "SELECT EmailAddress FROM table " +
                "WHERE EmailAddress=@EmailAddress; ",
                new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", previousEmail));

          if (data.Read())
              email = data.GetValue<string>(0);
      }
      return email;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex);
   }
}
```